# Can GWT ignore some lines of code?

Tags: java, html, gwt, libgdx

I'm actually working on a project with LibGDX, and for some reason, I have to use some java code that can't be used by GWT. 
(Example : c.newInstance() or java.util.Timer)

I would like GWT to ignore some lines, and pass directly to the correct line for it.

For example :

```
@GWTignore  
nodeModel.newInstance(); <--- will be ignored
@GWTcorrect
ClassReflection.newInstance(nodeModel); <--- will be accepted
```

I precise, it's lines of code that I want to ignore, not classes.
Do you think it is possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Gdx.app.GetType()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Application.html#getType--)

```
if(Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.WebGL){
        //do webgl stuff
    }else{
        //do non webgl stuff
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But this solution won't work because a part of my code has to be used without LibGDX. However, are you sure this solution will make GWT compile ? 

EDIT : I tried, and GWT doesn't accept this solution.

Comment: You use the @GwtIncompatible annotation for incompatible items http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/shared/GwtIncompatible.html

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for ! Thank you !
However, even thought I searched how to use it, I didn't find anything.

I just use LibGDX's GWT, and it can't find @gwtIncompatible.

Can you help me?

Comment: There are a few examples on this site https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.gwt.core.shared.GwtIncompatible